# Is there a way to check if a GTK widget supports a property without checking version numbers?

Tags: lua, gtk, lgi

According to the GTK API reference, the ["license-type"](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkAboutDialog.html#GtkAboutDialog--license-type) property of GtkAboutDialog is only present in GTK >= 3.0. For compatibility, my code currently checks the GTK version before setting the "license-type" property:

```lua
-- This is Lua code binding to GTK via lgi
local dialog = Gtk.AboutDialog {
    title = "About Me",
    -- ...,
}
if Gtk.check_version(3,0,0) == nil then
    dialog.license_type = Gtk.License.MIT_X11
end
```

Instead of doing this, is there a way to directly ask GTK if a widget supports a certain property? I think the code would be more self-documenting and less bug prone if I could write something that looks like

```lua
if supports_property(dialog, "license-type") then
    dialog.license_type = Gtk.License.MIT_X11
end
```

Since this question is really about the GTK API, I'm OK with answers in any programming language. Although the examples are in Lua, I assume a similar problem should show up in other dynamic-language bindings or even in C, assuming that there is a way to set properties by name without going through the `set_license_type` accessor function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the `_property` field like you are doing in your [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38647442/90511) since lgi finds all names in the type categories tables directly. Additionally, it is also possible to get type of an instance using `_type` accessor. So I'd recommend following solution:

```
if dialog._type.license_type then
    dialog.license_type = Gtk.License.MIT_X11
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`g_object_class_find_property()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-class-find-property) function to see if a property exists.

Note that this function takes a GObjectClass, not the GObject instance. All GObject classes come in these class-instance pairs, with the class structure used for shared things like vtable methods. To get the GObjectClass associated with an object instance, in C, you can use the [`G_OBJECT_GET_CLASS()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/2.40/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#G-OBJECT-GET-CLASS:CAPS) macro. (If you want to do this in Lua, and if Lua can't call C macros like that, you'll have to trace the definition of `G_OBJECT_GET_CLASS()`.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I never managed to find a way to call "find_property" in Lua because the Lua interface I used would wrap all the classes inside tables, and would not expose the GObjectClass pointers that "find_property" requires. The good news is that I found an alternative (Lua-only) way to solve my problem.

Comment: Good to know. Is this solution documented in lgi anywhere?

Comment: Dunno for sure, I kind of figured it out on my own. However, the `_property` table is a public API so I think its fine.

Answer (score 1):

In lgi, a class's properties are present in its _property field:

```
if Gtk.AboutDialog._property.license_type then
    dialog.license_type = Gtk.License.MIT_X11
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reasons you need to know if a property is present **without** instantiating it, you can go with @andlabs idea in this way:

```
local lgi   = require'lgi'
local Gtk   = lgi.require'Gtk'
local class = Gtk.AboutDialogClass()

-- Prints yes
if class:find_property('license') then print('yes') end

-- Does not print anything
if class:find_property('unknown') then print('yes') end
```